# What is "serial voting" on this site?

Tags: support, moderation

This site has less than 20 active users.  I can imagine quite easily that a few of them vote in concert because they are more or less like-minded.  I got a few rep points taken off for "serial voting".  It was about 10% of my overall rep.  So it wasn't indicative of any large trend that I can tell.

First, I want to make sure that it wasn't done by Yannis.  As much as he tries, he does allow himself more liberties to shape the direction of content rather than control its quality.  He recently challenged the motivation for my asking a certain question even though he conceded that the question's content was within the parameters of the site.  Vindictiveness is not something that should be expected from the moderators.  It erodes the trust in the process.

Answer (score 9):

Moderators cannot invalidate votes. This can happen either by an automated process or by a Stack Exchange employee. You may find more details in the [help centre](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).

In this instance, I noticed that you had received an inordinate amount of upvotes from a new-ish account. Investigating further, I found two more accounts that seemed to exist primarily to upvote your posts. Your main account shared IP addresses with all three accounts. You all also shared login times.

I alerted Stack Exchange, shared what I've found and asked them to take a closer look and invalidate any suspicious votes they find. They did and decided to invalidate a number of votes between the four accounts. I'm afraid this is all the information I can share. If you wish to find out more or to challenge my actions and Stack Exchange's decision to invalidate the votes, feel free to [contact them](https://politics.stackexchange.com/contact) directly. You may use [this link](https://politics.stackexchange.com/admin/cm-message/10#10) as a reference (the link will only work for people with diamond access to the site).

As for your last paragraph, again feel free to contact Stack Exchange directly. They take accusations against moderators very seriously, and I'm sure they'd be very interested to see any evidence of my misconduct you have collected.

PS. The site has a lot more [active voters](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) than you think.

Comment: The site does not have more active voters than I think. https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week

Comment: If moderators don't have an ability to reverse votes, then I don't understand this: "If such a voting pattern continues to happen between two users mutually or from one user towards another, or otherwise falls outside of normal voting patterns, **moderators** and/or developers may investigate the matter; intentionally voting merely to reduce or inflate another user's reputation is considered abuse."  It's part of this: https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: @grovkin Moderators can _investigate_ suspicious voting patterns. That's about it. We can't act on it. If we find anything fishy, SE takes over. As I've already explained in my answer.

Comment: I read more of your answer.  I do see what you are talking about.  There are 3 people in this household who use the site.  It's possible that one other used it from more than 1 computer.  You characterization of their activities as "solely existing to upvote my posts" is ridiculous.  I don't know how else to describe it.  You are being vindictive.  You do not like the *implications* of some of the questions I asked.  And I have strong doubts that you simply referred this pattern for an investigation rather than suggested what the results of the investigation should be.

Comment: @grovkin It is - of course - possible that I am mistaken. And this is the last I have to say on the matter. Anything else, you'll have to discuss with someone at Stack Exchange.

Comment: I alerted them at the same time as I posted the question here.

Comment: @grovkin I had a look at the voting trends of the accounts in question, and certainly looks to me like a small number of accounts that almost exclusively vote on each-other's posts, and not on posts outside that small circle

Comment: @grovkin It doesn't look to me like a voting pattern that can be sufficiently explained by them being "like-minded"

Comment: @SamIam, I don't know who the accounts are, but from the "same IP" claim it seems like it's the people in my household.  I don't think there is any rule about people in the same household voting for/against each other.  And I strongly doubt that most of my votes were for or by these individuals.  Especially since only 10% of rep was due to them.

Comment: @grovkin It's more than just some people from the same IP _sometimes_ voting for each-other.  It's a small circle of users that interact almost exclusively with each-other, and not with posts from other users.

Comment: @SamIam  then why is it only 10% of my rep?  And one of them just told me that I only had 1 out of about 10 votes on his rep.

Comment: @grovkin because your account seems to be the one account that interacts with the rest of the site.

Comment: @SamIam I am the most active of us on politics.  I know.  But why is that relevant?  At least one other is active on other SE sites.

Comment: @SamIam I do, from time to time, bring their attention to questions I find interesting... and vice versa.  Again, this is not that outlandish.

Comment: @SamIam, although the 10% of the rep kindda gives away the threshold set in the algorithm.  I suppose I can post an answer to my own question now.

Comment: @SamIam, on this SE site? or at all?  I did say that I am the most active on this SE site. And they sometimes read questions because I bring their attention to them.

Comment: @grovkin  If you do decide to contact support, you should do your best to explain your situation, and why you think it explains the suspicious voting patterns in a way that is not serial voting.  You won't get very far trying to convince them that the pattern doesn't even look suspicious, because, they'll look at the pattern, and it will look suspicious to them too.

Comment: @SamIam - As much as I'm enjoying this little exchange, you appear to be sharing privileged account information (regarding vote counts, etc)

Comment: @Valorum  I understand your point.  I was a bit nervous about that myself, which is why I was trying to avoid specifics of it.  I've deleted the post with the numbers.  It's served it's purpose since Grovkin has already seen it to understand it's point.

Comment: @grovkin looks like this case is actually more about [voting ring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137448/241919) (deliberately or not) in addition to serial voting... when there's a small group voting for each other almost exclusively, it will look suspicious, no matter what the situation.

Comment: @grovkin, I remember myself upvoting your posts quite often. However, nobody blames me for being your sockpuppet — probably because [I'm #4 voter](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) of all times on this site. If your family members distributed their contributions to this site more evenly (while still upvoting your posts), this would instantly sort out the whole problem. As for now, you will have hard time even proving that they are different people than you (since SE never demands our IDs like some evil social networks do).

Comment: Re: "The site does not have more active voters than I think. politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week" That page seems incorrect @grovkin. I have voted in the last week (verified on my profile/activity page), and for whatever reason I am not listed at all there.

Comment: @MartinTournoij That page is a) only showing people who voted more than 10 times in the selected timeframe and b) cached (i.e. data on it may not be entirely fresh).

Comment: @SamIam, yes, indeed, the additional stats which you let me see temporarily did allow me to gain more insight into why the rep reduction happened.  Speaking of serial voting though, I am concerned that the same group of voters always downvotes me out of spite.  Would it be possible to trigger an investigation of that?

Comment: @grovkin  I've looked voting trends for votes that you received, and there isn't that much unusual about it.  It does seem polarized, but not so much that it's not explained by people being "like-minded".

Comment: @SamIam I was just wondering if setting some threshold (let's say 50%) would show that that many (50%) or more of my downvotes came from less than 5-10 users.  Certainly if 10% (or more) of my downvotes came from 1 user, that would be a red flag, but I doubt it's that egregious.

Comment: @grovkin  I'm not sure what level of detail it is appropriate to share, but your vote received trends do not have that sort of outlier

Comment: @SamIam thanks for clearing that up.  I guess I am reading more than I should into people's sentiments.